# Consequence of application of activation function to input layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I wasn't aware of the fact that the activation function
gets applied for the first time during prop in the first hidden layer and not already in the neurons of the input layer.

If I now did otherwise but the data was already normalized before, what are the consequences for the further computation? Does it cause bias, ruin the feature representation, something else or no real impact at all?

What does even happen now in the input layer? weighted sum or not?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't come across with it anywhere to be honest. But, if you apply the activation function to the input layer, it'll correspond to a feature transformation, e.g. it's like taking the cube of all your features and inputting them to the neural network. It may not ruin your data always but note that neural nets typically benefit from zero-mean standardised inputs, because the hidden neurons tend to activate more in the linear region of sigmoid. And, that's useful for gradient descent.

Comment: I made this mistake though I got good results. But in some cases when the model  was overturning I attributed this to the small training set and a small imbalance left, which does make sense. But now I'm wondering, I used the same model with different activation functions and some were overturning more often than others, maybe due to this...?

Comment: It can, for example, if you use ReLU, you destroy all your negative feature values.